# Finding correlation of multiple columns in R

Tags: r, group-by, dataset, analytics

My requirement is to find the `Co-Relation` of `E_Id, IncomeType and Tax` to help understand if any `E_Id, IncomeType` always leads to higher `Tax`. My sample data for the required columns is

```
E_id           IncomeType                 Tax 
1                  1                    121
2                  1                    11.23
2                  3                    51.623
1                  1                    115.23
3                  4                    675.1
```

I have around 5 lacs of data, 4 types of IncomeType, 340 unique E_id. I grouped the data and now my data looks something like this:

```
E_Id    Tax_Income_1    Tax_Income_2    Tax_Income_3    Tax_Income_4
1         118025           66513.25          148134        274072.16
2         200527           235278            247536.42     487333.98
3         3376.93          11279             114312.5      130463.97
4         44630            22285.95          20830.55      2375
5         42902.63         15649             7602.01       3624
```

Now I don't have any idea how to find the correlation. This is my first analytics project, please provide some guidance.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to draw your attention to - correlation_table {funModeling}

```
data(mtcars)
correlation_table(data=mtcars, target="mpg")
```

```
Variable   mpg 
1      mpg  1.00 
2     drat  0.68 
3     gear  0.48 
4     qsec  0.42 
5     carb -0.55 
6       hp -0.78 
7      cyl -0.85 
8     disp -0.85 
9       wt -0.87
```

Answer (score 1):

Also using the mtcars data set as an example, the cor() unction will produce a matrix of variable correlations.

```
data(mtcars)
cor(mtcars)
```

You can also graphically represent these correlations:

```
corrgram(mtcars)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the mtcars dataset as an example you can visualize the correlations of all the variables like this:

```
data(mtcars)
pairs(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
```

[image]